# Aframe calculate position in local system from world position.

Tags: three.js, aframe

I've got a component to animate to a position in front of the camera, but when it's a child of another object this is animating in the wrong direction (away from the camera) because it's using the world position in an entity.

I know it's because of world coordinates.. can anyone help tell me how to convert this world position into local coordinates?

```
    pLocal= new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -distX)
   this._targetPosition = pLocal.applyMatrix4(this._threeCamera.matrixWorld)
```

I this example the box is a child of the sphere and animates away from the camera.
https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsrnq1/2/

If the box is not a child it animates towards camera. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsrnq1/3/

How do I make it animate to camera when it's a child of another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `worldToLocal()` method:

from the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D):

> .worldToLocal ( vector : Vector3 ) : Vector3 
>    Updates the vector from world space to local space.

by using the method on your parent: `parentObj.worldToLocal(vec)` you can apply its world position to the local position vector. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsrnq1/6/).

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsrnq1/5/).

---

Another way would be looping through parent entities, and subtracting their positions, but it doesn't seem to have any advantage over the `worldToLocal` method

Comment: Definitely the first way. The second way does not take into account rotations, scales, additional ancestors.

Comment: true, it would requre looping through ancestors until you reach the scene, which is pretty much redundant when you can use `worldToLocal ()`

Comment: Thanks @PiotrAdamMilewski that's awesome. I knew it was something to do with this function was struggling working out where it gets applied.

Comment: @user5839 glad i could help :)

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I've brought this into my code and this.el.parentNode.object3D.worldToLocal(this._targetPosition) isn't making any changes to the targetPosition. Should it be?

Comment: Ahh because the parent is at {0,0,0}.